# The content published by wagtail using the RichTextField field does not support spaces and indents

Tags: django, blogs, wagtail

I am a beginner and use the blog developed by wagtail to take notes. After the record code part is saved, the blank space and indentation disappear. This problem is stuck. Help me. Thank you！

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
```

saved e.g:

```
class BlogPage(Page):
body = RichTextField(blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little hard to tell where you are looking at the body content - in the editor? or on the rendered page? For the front end, please make sure you are using the [richtext filter](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/topics/writing_templates.html#rich-text-filter) in your html template. But note that html doesn't preserve spacing and indentation (unless you are using a  or  tag).

Comment: How to preserve spacing and indentation?Thanks